# Date for Amazon Turk REST Call java

Tags: java, datetime, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to call:

```
https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester
&AWSAccessKeyId=[the Requester's Access Key ID]
&Version=2012-03-25
&Operation=ApproveRejectedAssignment
&Signature=[signature for this request]
&Timestamp=[your system's local time]
&AssignmentId=123RVWYBAZW00EXAMPLE456RVWYBAZW00EXAMPLE
```

I need the signature, which requires a UTC timestamp of the format `YYYY:dd:MMTHH:mm:ss-Offset` like `2012-05-25T11:30:47-07:00`

I'm trying to use the java tools given [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/MakingRequests_RequestAuthenticationArticle.html) to make the signature, but I can't get the Date to be formatted correctly.

I'm also game for using the SDK, but couldn't figure out where to even begin with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 2012-06-23T00:03:52-0700
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    //Local time zone   
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    //Time in GMT
    String[] datetime = dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()).split(" ");
    String date = datetime[0];
    String time = datetime[1];

    System.out.print(date+"T"+time+"Z");
```